# Median of every row in R, hundreds of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is very similar to this one:  [Min and Median of Multiple Columns of a DF by Row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902842/min-and-median-of-multiple-columns-of-a-df-by-row-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)
And I know has been asked in a variety of ways, but I don't feel that they adequately address my question.

I have a data frame with 260ish columns.  I'd like to get the median of every row, preferably using dplyr as its what I'm comfortable with.  The answer from the above linked question is almost perfect, doing something like:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(median = median(c(V1, V2, V3)))
```

Would work and accomplish exactly what I ask, but much like this question: [Sum across multiple columns with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873057/sum-across-multiple-columns-with-dplyr)

I'd rather not write out the names of 260ish columns.  Is there a way to take the above command and modify it so it inputs all 260 columns?

Comment: Look into `c_across`, e.g. `mutate(median = median(c_across())`

Comment: Worked perfectly once I realized my columns were all character class.  Which is weird because if I just simply used median on two individual columns prior to fixing that, it worked just fine.  Oh well.  Thank you!

Comment: If all of your data is numeric, why can't you just use `apply` as suggested in your reference link?  I.e., `medians <- apply(df, 1, median)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using a numeric dataset and tidy verse

libraries used dplyr, purrr

```r
library(tidyverse)


diabetes<-read.csv(url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv'))


diabetes$row_median = t(map(data.frame(t(diabetes)),median) %>% bind_cols())
```